# No envia mensaje de whatsapp con python

Tags: python, whatsapp

Intento enviar un mensaje de whatsapp con pywhatkit.
El código es el siguiente:

```
import pywhatkit
pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg("numero tlf","mensaje prueba desde python",19,15)
print("enviado")
```

El número de teléfono puesto es un ejemplo, no es el número real.
El problema es que el mensaje no es enviado.
Llega a la web de whatsapp pero no lo envía.
¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?
Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: Tengo mis reservas respecto de que funcione así, sin más. Date cuenta que éso significaría que se podría mandar spam por whatsapp (bastaría con ir iterando numero a número de teléfono) y yo no estoy recibiendo spam por whatsapp, así que algo está fallando....

Comment: No he investigado mucho sobre esta librería, pero si el problema es que se queda el mensaje sin enviar basta con poner \r al final del string del mensaje para que lo interprete como la tecla intro.
eg. pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg("+58XXXXXXXXXX", "esta es una prueba de mensaje desde python\r", 14, 46, 30)

Answer (score 0):

El primer parámetro de la llamada es

```
phone_num (required) - Phone number of target with country code
```

que debe ser especificado con código de país, área y número (tal cual en la aplicación WS).

Parece que '11111111' no es un valor aceptable.

Comment: Hola. He puesto esos números por no poner el numero de teléfono verdadero.

Comment: @raul. Lo apropiado es poner el número y pixelarlo. De esa manera nos damos cuenta que estás usando el formato correcto sin necesidad de exponer datos privados.

Answer (score 0):

Primero tienes que abrir el explorador preferido de tu PC, abrir whatsapp web y agregarlo desde tu app de tu móvil. No puedes cerrar la web, debes dejarla abierta. Cada mensaje que envíes abrirá una sesión nueva y deshabilitará la anterior. Pero funciona.

Answer (score 0):

me pasaba lo mismo, pero busque en internet y consegui este link

[en este link explican, que eso pasa porque a veces 15 segundos no es suficiente porque el internet no es rápido, solo coloca como cuarto parámetro 30 segundos y listo!](https://www.mejorcodigo.com/p/137121.html)

```
pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg("+58XXXXXXXXXX", "esta es una prueba de mensaje desde python", 14, 46, 30)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_instantly("+58xxxxxxxxx", "Mensaje desde Python usando la libreria Pywhatkit, conforme si te llego el mensaje")
```

Esta instruccion envia mensaje a whatsapp directamente sin necesidad de abrir whatsapp web.

Lo malo es que se tiene dar un ENTER al mensaje en whatsapp para que el mensaje sea enviado

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que al abrir el navegador la la ventana del mismo deja de ser "ventana activa o enfocada", entonces lo que hace Pywhatkit es que simula un enter para enviar el mensaje de texto, pero como deja de ser ventana activa, esa simulación se pierde.

Lo que se puede hacer en este caso es agregar pyautogui para volver a tomar la ventana del navegador como "ventana activa o enfocada" ¿Cómo hacemos esto?

Tenemos que instalar pyautogui con el comando

```
pip install pyautogui
```

Pueden revisar la [documentación](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) en su sitio web, para que comprendan un poco más sobre el mismo.

También debemos tener Tkinter, que es es la interfaz por defecto de Python para el kit de herramientas de GUI Tk.

Posteriormente a esto debemos importarlo en nuestro código Python:

```
import pyautogui
```

Así como Tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
```

Entonces en nuestro código debemos tener hacer un *"truquito"*, debemos tomar la altura y anchura de la pantalla donde se abrirá el navegador al usar Pywhatkit y esas medidas dividirlas entre 2

```
 win = Tk()
 pantalla_ancho = win.winfo_screenwidth()
 pantalla_alto = win.winfo_screenheight()
```

**Nota:** Estas medidas, son opcionales a dividir entre 2, puede ser alguna otra medida, realmente solo en eje X, el eje Y siempre entre dos.

Al tener estas medidas son para recuperar la "ventana activa" ¿Pero cómo? Muy fácil, despues de tener estar medidas aplicaremos la simulación de un "clic" con:

```
pyautogui.click()
```

Entonces de esta manera recuperaremos la "ventana activa" de una manera sencilla.
Inclusive si no tenemos el navegador como "ventana enfocada", pues a que PyWhatKit abre el navegador y a su vez una pestaña en WhatsApp Web ¡Así que no nos preocupemos!

Bueno, regresando al tema, después de generar el clic, ahora simularemos un enter con pyautogui:

```
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

Y de esta manera será envíado el mensaje por WhatsApp de manera correcta ¿Sencillo, no?

Les dejo un fragmento de mi código que desarrolle:

```
import pywhatkit
import pyautogui
from tkinter import *

// Aquí tomamos las medidas de nuestras pantalla para posteriormente
// volver a recuperar la "ventana activa"
win = Tk()
pantalla_ancho = win.winfo_screenwidth()
pantalla_alto = win.winfo_screenheight()

// Aquí enviamos el mensaje WhatsApp, se abrirá el navegador pero perdemos 
// control sobre el navegador como "ventana enfocada"
pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg(+520000000000, mensaje, hora, minuto)

// Con el siguiente código recuperamos el navegador como "ventana activa"
pyautogui.moveTo(pantalla_ancho / 2, pantalla_alto / 2)
pyautogui.click()

//Recuperamos la "ventana enfocada" pero ocuparemos simular un enter para envío
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

Les dejo mi [repositorio](https://github.com/JuanMinorMX/ChanguiBot.git) de mi código con PyWhatKit, es un poco más avanzado, hice que Python leyera un archivo Excel CSV y enviará mensajes WhatsApp de manera masiva ¡Espero les funcione!